# Upgrading Ant to 1.8.1 via macports

Tags: ant, macports

I'm trying to upgrade ant to 1.8.1 via macports.

When I run live-check I get this:
apache-ant seems to have been updated (port version: 1.7.1, new version: 1.8.1)

but when i run port install it installs 1.7.1 and when I run upgrade it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use MacPorts?  Ant is very simple to install yourself.  Just [download](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), extract somewhere (I usually use `/opt/ant`) and add to your `$PATH`.

Comment: OTOH once installed through Macports, it would be easier to update, presumably, using the batch "upgrade installed" command.

Comment: Sure.  But it's not that difficult to do by hand either.  Untar, add a symlink to a name in your path and you're away.  Yes, this duplicates work from macports.  But it assumes you can get macports to work, which the OP can't.